# Remove records with empty fields and move fields with values to another record

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-design

I've got the following access table with empty fields:

```
Analyse   Analysed  Finished    FAR_Send   RMA
Product1
                                Product2  
          Product3
                    Product4
                    Product5
          Product6
                    Product7
                                           Product8
                                           Product9
                    Product10
                                           Product11
```

I want to change this to the following:

```
Analyse   Analysed  Finished    FAR_Send   RMA
Product1  Product3  Product4    Product2   Product8
          Product6  Product5               Product9
                    Product7               Product11
                    Product10
```

Can this be done with standard queries and without VB programming ?

Best regards,

Wamor

Comment: Firstly, an example is just an example.  We still need to know the rules.  Maybe we can infer them but then we might be wrong.  If you were to be explicit then there could be no confusion. Secondly, if your request is to do this in SQL and not VB then why is this question tagged with VB.NET?

Comment: Your example looks like you're using Access as you would a spreadsheet.  It would be far easier if your table had two fields - Product & Status.  This would then have 11 records such as `Product1 | Analyse`, `Product2 | Far_Send`.  You could then use something like `TRANSFORM Count(Status) AS CountOfStatus SELECT Product FROM MyTable GROUP BY Product ORDER BY Product PIVOT Status`

Answer (score 1):

The table needs a unique identifier - an autonumber field will probably serve. Then consider:

Query1:
`SELECT ID, "Analyse" AS Category, Analyse AS Data FROM Tablename WHERE Not Analyse Is Null
UNION SELECT ID, "Analysed", Analysed FROM Tablename WHERE Not Analysed Is Null
UNION SELECT ID, "Finished", Finished FROM Tablename WHERE Not Finished Is Null
UNION SELECT ID, "FAR_Send", FAR_Send FROM Tablename WHERE Not FAR_Send Is Null
UNION SELECT ID, "RMA", RMA FROM Tablename WHERE Not RMA Is Null;`

Query2:
`TRANSFORM First(Query1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT DCount("*","Query1","Category='" & [Category] & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1 AS Seq
FROM Query1
GROUP BY DCount("*","Query1","Category='" & [Category] & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1
PIVOT Query1.Category;`